# An optional element in C# RegEx matching expression

Tags: c#, regex

How to make 'test2' an optional element in the following C# RegEx expression getting 'test1' value parsed out correctly when 'test2' element is missing?

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendLine("    test1=123 any text in between  ");
 sb.AppendLine(" some ");
 sb.AppendLine(" more ");
 sb.AppendLine(" text in between ");
 sb.AppendLine("    test2=456   ");
 sb.AppendLine("    test1=789  some text .. test2=012   ");

 Regex regex = new Regex(@"test1=(?<test1>(\d+))((.|\s)+?)(test2=(?<test2>(\d+)))");

 MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(sb.ToString());
 foreach (Match match in matches)
 {
     Group test1 = match.Groups["test1"];
     Group test2 = match.Groups["test2"];                
     System.Console.WriteLine("Test1 = {0}, Test2 = {1}", test1.Value, test2.Value);
 }
```

Thank you.

---

@Oded - I reply here as I can't get comment formatted properly and as my reply is longer than allowed by StackOverflow comment text length:

---

Thank you. Proposed in your second reply RegEx expression results in the following output:

```
 Test1 = 123, Test2 = 
 Test1 = 789, Test2 =
```

It's not quite correct.
And your first reply RegEx expression results in

```
 Test1 = 123, Test2 = 456
 Test1 = 789, Test2 = 012
```

test output. That's is correct.

But if I change

```
sb.AppendLine("    test1=789  some text .. test2=012   ");
```

to

```
sb.AppendLine("    test1=789  some text .. test52=012   ");
```

then the test result output will have just one line

```
Test1 = 123, Test2 = 456
```

and I wanted it to be

```
 Test1 = 123, Test2 = 456
 Test1 = 789, Test2 =
```

in that case.

Answer (score 8):

Qualify that the whole `test2` group is optional:

```
@"test1=(?<test1>(\d+))((.|\s)+?)(test2=(?<test2>(\d+)))?"
```

From MSDN - [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx):

> ? - 
>   Matches the previous element zero or one time.

Comment: Thank you. As my test run shows here if I add question mark in my RegEx expressoion as you proposed then 'test1' element will be also missing if 'test2' is missing.

Comment: @ShamilS - Sorry, I misplaced the `?`.

Comment: @ShamilS - I can't read that. Perhaps edit your question and add it there?

Comment: sorry, I have just replied in my question area.

Comment: @ShamilS - You have now clarified the _actual_ requirements somewhat. I don't have an immediate answer.

Comment: Thank you. It can wait. Please reply later if you'll find how to make my code working against _actual_ requirements. I did use .IndexOf(...), .Substring(...) and related stuff wrapped into custom functions before. I have to continue using them now. I have just learned RegEx today, and it didn't work well enough for my subject area. It could be not right tool for that job.

Answer (score 2):

add a ? after the element you want to be optional

`.|\s`can be replaced by `.` since `.` matches whitespace as well

To match newlines as well you have to pass Singleline option `Regex regex = new Regex(@"test1=(?<test1>(\d+))((.)+?)(test2=(?<test2>(\d+)))?",RegexOptions.Singleline);`

(The solution by Oded is does all this)

Comment: Thank you. Please see my comment above.

Comment: I do use (.|\s) to have any chars as well as new line (chars) skipped - . alone seems to be not good enough.

Comment: @ShamilS: If you want the `.` class to match newlines, turn on the "DOTALL" option of your regex. (In Python this is `re.DOTALL`, in Perl this is the `s` option. Look up what it is in C#.)

Comment: in c# you have to pass `RegexOptions.Singleline` in your case to the constructor.

Comment: @ShamilS this might become a lot easier if you just match twice...once with (test1=\d+) then with (test2=\d+) . (Assuming you just want to extract those strings)

Comment: Thank you. RegexOptions.Singleline does do the 'trick'. My RegEx expression is now looking as the following: __@"test1=(?<test1>(\d+))(.+?)(test2=(?<test2>(\d+)))"__

Comment: Further note, my last comment only applies if you don't care for order or test1 / test2 strings. If you do you could also do this with String.IndexOf

Comment: @msam - Matching twice: yes, I know, but I wanted to try to make it in one go as I need/wanted to parse input text lines (with optional elements) into (anonymous types) object instances in one go/one RegEx expression IOW I wanted to avoid "merging" two (or more) matches. RegEx could happen to be not right tool for my task - then I will use something different (e.g. plain text parsing, splitting input text into text blocks and then applying individual RegEx expressions/merging results into (anonymous types) object instances etc. - but first I wanted to get expert opinions/advices here...